# Apps don't run on iPhone after upgrading to Xcode 4.2 and iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

since upgrading to Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5 I can no longer run my apps on my iPhone. They still run fine in the simulator.
I was using Snow Leopard with 4.2 and thought this might be the problem, so upgraded to Lion and then upgraded Xcode to the 4.2.1 Lion version. However this did not solve the problem.
I've been through many of the threads trying to find something similar but can't. I've also tried out different build settings, compilers, deployment targets etc.
I'm pretty sure this is not a provisioning problem, as the apps load onto the device, it's just that they never launch properly, if the app has a launch image this is where it locks up. I've also tried just running the default Xcode templates, to no avail.
I've tried deleting the derived data, cleaning the projects, removing and then re importing the frameworks from the projects, but nothing changes.

These are the errors I'm getting

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
warning: Unable to read symbols from "UIKit" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "Foundation" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "CoreGraphics" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "libSystem.B.dylib" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "CoreFoundation" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "libobjc.A.dylib" (not yet mapped into memory).
```

and then I get a bunch of these, they go on for 15 lines

```
warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally, reading from memory on remote device.   This may slow down the debug session.
warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
```

and then I get a bunch of these that go on and on with every framework you could possibly think of and then some

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit (file not found).
warning: No copy of UIKit.framework/UIKit found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation (file not found).
warning: No copy of Foundation.framework/Foundation found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics (file not found).
warning: No copy of CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of libSystem.B.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation (file not found).
warning: No copy of CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of libobjc.A.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface (file not found).
warning: No copy of IOSurface.framework/IOSurface found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (file not found).
warning: No copy of IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of liblockdown.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag (file not found).
warning: No copy of MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of libicucore.A.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage (file not found).
warning: No copy of CoreImage.framework/CoreImage found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security (file not found).
```

So my guess is (and I could be wrong) it looks like Xcode doesn't know where the frameworks are, but only when my device is connected. I don't know how to solve this problem and would greatly appreciate any help or ideas
thanks

Comment: I would check whether the directory `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)` is there.

Comment: Thank you I will check tonight, and what should I do if it is not?

Comment: Then there is something wrong with you installation. In this case I would try to reinstall Xcode and the newest SDK.

Comment: Hey Dasdom that folder exists, it contains a single folder called Symbols, should it contain more? Inside Symbols there are two more folders "Developer" and "System" and "usr". Should it contain actual files. I've already reinstalled the latest SDK twice, once for Leopard and then again for Lion, but I will try again, I have no other choice.

Comment: hey thanks for your help Dasdom, although it turns out I needed the full uninstall, not just the reinstall as I had been doing and you had suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I ended up doing a full uninstall in Terminal, then reinstalling Xcode. It turns out that just installing over the top of the previous version doesn't correct the error. It needs a full uninstall first. Now everything works as it should

Comment: just had to wait the 8 hours yo

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem reinstalling Xcode didn't correct it. In the end I closed xcode and renamed the folder developer/platforms/ipho eps.platform/device support/5.0.1 (9a334) as old then reconnecting the device. This folder was rebuilt and everything was right in the world again.

Comment: hey I read your answer 2 minutes after I started uninstalling XCode, so can't confirm if it would work or not, but thanks for the help